# Extract class from static and templated member functions

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming, pointer-to-member

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>

struct object
{
    void f0(int i) {std::cout<<i<<std::endl;}
    void f1(int i) const {std::cout<<i<<std::endl;}
    void f2(int i) volatile {std::cout<<i<<std::endl;}
    void f3(int i) const volatile {std::cout<<i<<std::endl;}
    constexpr int f4(int i) const noexcept {return i;}
    static void f5(int i) {std::cout<<i<<std::endl;}
    template <class T> void f(T i) {std::cout<<i<<std::endl;}
};

template <class T, class C>
void print_class_containing(T C::* ptr)
{
    std::cout<<"typeid(C).name() = "<<typeid(C).name()<<std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout<<"typeid(object).name() = "<<typeid(object).name()<<std::endl;
    print_class_containing(&object::f0);
    print_class_containing(&object::f1);
    print_class_containing(&object::f2);
    print_class_containing(&object::f3);
    print_class_containing(&object::f4);
    //print_class_containing(&object::f5); -> Not compiling
    //print_class_containing(&object::f); -> Not compiling
    return 0;
}
```

How to write a function, and how to call it, to print the class that is "containing" a pointer to static member function (`f5`), and pointer to templated member function (`f`)?

Currently, the compiler returns:

```
static_member.cpp:30:5: error: no matching function for call to 'print_class_containing'
    print_class_containing(&object::f5); // -> Not compiling
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
static_member.cpp:17:6: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'T C::*' against 'void (*)(int)'
void print_class_containing(T C::* ptr)
     ^
static_member.cpp:31:5: error: no matching function for call to 'print_class_containing'
    print_class_containing(&object::f); // -> Not compiling
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
static_member.cpp:17:6: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'
void print_class_containing(T C::* ptr)
     ^
2 errors generated.
```

Comment: Pointer-to-member is only used for non-static member functions. Taking address of a static member function produces a normal function pointer, just as a non-member function would. A static member function is just a regular function with a fancy name.

Comment: A function template is not a single function - it's a potentially infinite family of functions. You cannot take address of them all, you can only take an address of a particular instantiation, e.g. `&object::f<int>`.